# Why Cricket commentators read out score after every over?

Tags: cricket, media

I have been noticing from a very long time, Cricket commentators read out score after every over. Why is it so?

Is there any historical significance, tragedy or story behind it?

Comment: There is an old adage in baseball radio broadcasting, it basically goes "read the score at every opportunity." The idea behind it is to make sure a listener who just joined in can find out the score as quickly as possible (as there is no visual reference on the radio). I'd assume the reasoning in cricket is similar.

Comment: @waxeagle Gone those days!But these days we can see the scors any time..then?History continues or something like that?

Comment: @joeyrohan, Can not agree on that. Still there are far remote places you have never been before where radio plays a pivotal role.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cricket like baseball is a sport that actually works quite well on the radio, and many commentators on the sport commentate on radio as well as TV.

In such 'voice only' circumstances you want to give your audience a summary of the score at frequent intervals, and with Cricket you have the natural cadence of the 'over' of ~6 balls, so this is often used.  The habit has carried through to many TV commentators, as often people will 'watch' a long test match for example with only half an eye on the TV.

Comment: I would also like to add that not every people are sitting in front of a TV. So people who want to listen to ball-by-ball update via radio for example, can get it by the commentries.

Answer (score 1):

Cricket commentators read out the score so that people know what the score is. It's part and parcel of good fundamental sports commentary - reminding the viewer/listener how the game is progressing.

I am not sure if there was actually a time where the score was not given by an announcer at frequent intervals. For a fast scoring game like cricket (compared to, sy, the 0-0 draws of soccer) it's a bit of a given.

Answer (score 1):

The score changes a lot in cricket, so you would mention it more often.

It also serves as an excellent punctuation, to tell everyone there are commercials coming up - what better way for a commentator to close a section of airtime than reporting the current score?